# UITableViewController [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' with PFTask thenCallBackOnMainThreadAsync:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am purposely creating a empty Array to not display anything on the UITablewView.

However, it gives me that error.

To debug, I even created an empty UITableViewController and refer storyboard file to this. However, it is giving me the same error.

I just tried and connect it with an empty UIViewController, it is giving me the same objectAtIndex error.

So I doubt it is the problem with the what I am indexing for cells.

When I run, the screen is shown but it throws the error and it freezes.

The declaration of the newsList is:

`@property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *newsList`

This is what I have for the UITableViewController.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.currentUser = appDelegate.currentUser;

    NSString *addNewsFeed = @"_NewsFeed";


    if (self.currentUser)
    {


        if (appDelegate.selectedGroup == nil)
        {
            self.newsList = nil;


        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"SELECTED GROUP EXIST");
            NSString *currentNewsFeed = [appDelegate.selectedGroup[@"name"] stringByAppendingString:addNewsFeed];

            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:currentNewsFeed];
            [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

                if (error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
                else
                {
                    self.newsList = objects;
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                }
            }];
        }



    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.currentUser);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginView" sender:self];

    }

    NSLog(@"ZXCVZCVZ: %@", self.newsList);



}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (appDelegate.selectedGroup == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"NO CELL HERE");

        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (appDelegate.selectedGroup == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"NO CELL");
        return 0;
    }

    return [self.newsList count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"NO LIST FOUND");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"News";
    NSLog(@"DSFSDFSDFSFS");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PFObject *item = [self.newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = item[@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = item[@"news"];

    return cell;



}
```

Comment: could u provide what exact error your getting?

Comment: Please post the declaration of the newsList property.

Comment: @danh I just posted!

Comment: Where is the exception stack trace that you should provide with any exception-related question??

Answer (score 0):

you need to allocate the memory for array as below

```
self.newsList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//At viewWIllAppear
```

Without alloc the self.newsList you cannot able to store any records in it...

Hope it fixes...

Comment: The OP replaces newsList with the query result, so this init will have no effect.  Before the query result, the nil array will have a count == 0, which will prevent call to cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: If he wasn't allocating the array he wouldn't get the error.